# Linux takes long time to boot after resizing and moving partitions

Tags: systemd, startup, fstab

A while ago i installed a new NVME drive in my computer and installed Windows on it. I removed the old Windows installation from my old SSD so that my Linux installation could use all of it. I then moved the root Linux partition to the left and and expanded it to fill the space that Windows previously used. I also copied some files from the EFI partition on the NVME to the SSD to be able to use systemd-boot.

Now to the problem: after doing this Linux takes really long to boot (Windows works fine). Here is the output from `systemd-analyze`:

```
Startup finished in 18.338s (firmware) + 1.492s (loader) + 4.869s (kernel) + 1min 34.689s (userspace) = 1min 59.389s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 34.684s in userspace
```

`systemd-analyze blame`:

```
4.745s dev-sda6.device                                                                          
4.291s plymouth-quit-wait.service                                                               
 898ms mysql.service                                                                            
 740ms snapd.service                                                                            
 665ms systemd-logind.service                                                                   
 535ms accounts-daemon.service                                                                  
 517ms networkd-dispatcher.service                                                              
 323ms udisks2.service                                                                          
 257ms system76-power.service                                                                   
 220ms snap-snapd-10492.mount                                                                   
 216ms fwupd.service                                                                            
 210ms dev-loop0.device                                                                         
 208ms snap-flutter-40.mount                                                                    
 199ms systemd-journal-flush.service                                                            
 182ms snap-core18-1944.mount                                                                   
 177ms snap-snapd-10238.mount                                                                   
 167ms ModemManager.service                                                                     
 144ms snap-flutter-36.mount                                                                    
 138ms teamviewerd.service                                                                      
 137ms polkit.service                                                                           
 136ms dev-loop1.device                                                                         
 135ms avahi-daemon.service                                                                     
 134ms NetworkManager.service                                                                   
 126ms systemd-resolved.service                                                                 
 123ms switcheroo-control.service                                                               
 117ms thermald.service                                                                         
 116ms wpa_supplicant.service                                                                   
 116ms systemd-machined.service                                                                 
 115ms systemd-modules-load.service                                                             
 114ms upower.service                                                                           
 111ms snap-core18-1932.mount                                                                   
 107ms systemd-timesyncd.service                                                                
  99ms user@1000.service                                                                        
  97ms lvm2-monitor.service                                                                     
  95ms dev-loop2.device                                                                         
  94ms dev-loop3.device                                                                         
  84ms apparmor.service                                                                         
  77ms gdm.service                                                                              
  77ms gpu-manager.service                                                                      
  61ms systemd-udevd.service                                                                    
  60ms systemd-journald.service                                                                 
  55ms colord.service                                                                           
  55ms systemd-udev-trigger.service                                                             
  52ms rsyslog.service                                                                          
  50ms dev-loop4.device                                                                         
  49ms libvirtd.service                                                                         
  47ms apport.service                                                                           
  42ms keyboard-setup.service                                                                   
  37ms update-notifier-download.service                                                         
  32ms e2scrub_reap.service                                                                     
  32ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ebb2d3f4\x2d5518\x2d4c00\x2d9298\x2dfb3a4b774f78.swap                
  32ms qemu-kvm.service                                                                         
  29ms plymouth-start.service                                                                   
  28ms networking.service                                                                       
  24ms lm-sensors.service                                                                       
  22ms dev-loop5.device                                                                         
  20ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9d66c204\x2dfe76\x2d4fcb\x2d8ca3\x2d27acc6c41576.service
  20ms snapd.seeded.service                                                                     
  18ms home.mount                                                                               
  16ms alsa-restore.service                                                                     
  14ms snapd.apparmor.service                                                                   
  14ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service                                                           
  14ms systemd-sysctl.service                                                                   
  12ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service                                                         
  12ms modprobe@drm.service                                                                     
  11ms plymouth-read-write.service                                                              
  11ms systemd-sysusers.service                                                                 
  11ms nvidia-persistenced.service                                                              
  10ms pppd-dns.service                                                                         
   9ms dev-hugepages.mount                                                                      
   9ms dev-mqueue.mount                                                                         
   9ms systemd-random-seed.service                                                              
   9ms libvirt-guests.service                                                                   
   8ms sys-kernel-debug.mount                                                                   
   8ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount                                                                 
   8ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service                                                           
   7ms blk-availability.service                                                                 
   6ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service                                                       
   6ms systemd-update-utmp.service                                                              
   6ms systemd-remount-fs.service                                                               
   6ms boot-efi.mount                                                                           
   6ms kmod-static-nodes.service                                                                
   6ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service                                                            
   5ms hddtemp.service                                                                          
   5ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount                                                            
   4ms systemd-user-sessions.service                                                            
   4ms tmp.mount                                                                                
   4ms sys-kernel-config.mount                                                                  
   3ms ufw.service                                                                              
   3ms rtkit-daemon.service                                                                     
   3ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service                                                     
   2ms console-setup.service                                                                    
   2ms finalrd.service                                                                          
   2ms ifupdown-pre.service                                                                     
   1ms setvtrgb.service                                                                         
 955us libvirtd.socket                                                                          
 560us snapd.socket
```

`systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 34.684s
└─multi-user.target @1min 34.684s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @1min 30.392s +4.291s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1min 30.385s +4ms
      └─network.target @1min 30.380s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 30.245s +134ms
          └─dbus.service @1min 30.243s
            └─basic.target @1min 30.239s
              └─sockets.target @1min 30.239s
                └─libvirtd-ro.socket @1min 30.239s
                  └─libvirtd.socket @1min 30.238s +955us
                    └─sysinit.target @1min 30.233s
                      └─systemd-timesyncd.service @5.040s +107ms
                        └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @5.024s +14ms
                          └─local-fs.target @5.021s
                            └─home.mount @5.002s +18ms
                              └─systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9d66c204\x2dfe76\x2d4fcb\x2d8ca3\x2d27acc6c41576.service @4.981s +20ms
                                └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-9d66c204\x2dfe76\x2d4fcb\x2d8ca3\x2d27acc6c41576.device @4.973s
```

I see nothing in `blame` or `critical-chain` that takes unusually long time, but looking at `boot.log` from the last boot, i see the following:

```
[  OK  ] Finished Tell Plymouth To Write Out Runtime Data.
[  OK  ] Finished Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting Network Name Resolution...
         Starting Network Time Synchronization...
         Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
[  OK  ] Finished Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Finished QEMU KVM preparation - module, ksm, hugepages.
[  OK  ] Finished Load AppArmor profiles.
         Starting Raise network interfaces...
         Starting Load AppArmor pro…managed internally by snapd...
[  OK  ] Finished Load AppArmor pro…s managed internally by snapd.
[  OK  ] Finished Raise network interfaces.
[  OK  ] Started Network Time Synchronization.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Time Set.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Time Synchronized.
[  OK  ] Started Network Name Resolution.
[  OK  ] Reached target Host and Network Name Lookups.
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device -1259-4770-ba01-32b86790a561.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Cryptography Setup for cryptswap.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local Encrypted Volumes.
[  OK  ] Reached target Block Devic…ion for /dev/mapper/cryptswap.
[  OK  ] Reached target System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Started ACPI Events Check.
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Started resolvconf-pull-resolved.path.
[  OK  ] Started Daily apt download activities.
[  OK  ] Started Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
[  OK  ] Started Periodic ext4 Onli…ata Check for All Filesystems.
[  OK  ] Started Discard unused blocks once a week.
[  OK  ] Started Refresh fwupd metadata regularly.
[  OK  ] Started Daily rotation of log files.
[  OK  ] Started Daily man-db regeneration.
[  OK  ] Started Message of the Day.
[  OK  ] Started Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Reached target Paths.
[  OK  ] Listening on ACPID Listen Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Listening on D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
         Starting Libvirt local socket.
         Starting Socket activation for snappy daemon.
[  OK  ] Listening on UUID daemon activation socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Virtual machine lock manager socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Virtual machine lock manager admin socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Virtual machine log manager socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Virtual machine log manager socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Libvirt local socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.
[  OK  ] Stopped target Block Devic…ion for /dev/mapper/cryptswap.
[  OK  ] Listening on Libvirt admin socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on Libvirt local read-only socket.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sockets.
[  OK  ] Reached target Basic System.
         Starting Accounts Service...
[  OK  ] Started ACPI event daemon.
         Starting LSB: automatic crash report generation...
         Starting Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
[  OK  ] Started Regular background program processing daemon.
[  OK  ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Reached target Printer.
[  OK  ] Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
         Starting Network Manager...
[  OK  ] Started Save initial kernel messages after boot.
         Starting Remove Stale Onli…t4 Metadata Check Snapshots...
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
         Starting Detect the availa…eal with any system changes...
[  OK  ] Started irqbalance daemon.
         Starting Initialize hardware monitoring sensors...
         Starting Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd...
         Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
         Starting Authorization Manager...
[  OK  ] Started Pop Upgrade Daemon.
         Starting Restore /etc/reso… the ppp link was shut down...
         Starting resolvconf-pull-resolved.service...
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting Snap Daemon...
         Starting Switcheroo Control Proxy service...
         Starting System76 Power Daemon...
         Starting User Login Management...
         Starting Virtual Machine a…tainer Registration Service...
         Starting Thermal Daemon Service...
         Starting Disk Manager...
         Starting WPA supplicant...
[  OK  ] Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
[  OK  ] Finished Restore /etc/reso…re the ppp link was shut down.
[  OK  ] Finished Initialize hardware monitoring sensors.
[  OK  ] Finished Remove Stale Onli…ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: automatic crash report generation.
[  OK  ] Finished resolvconf-pull-resolved.service.
[  OK  ] Started System Logging Service.
[  OK  ] Finished Detect the availa… deal with any system changes.
[  OK  ] Started Virtual Machine an…ontainer Registration Service.
[  OK  ] Started Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[  OK  ] Started WPA supplicant.
[  OK  ] Started Thermal Daemon Service.
[  OK  ] Started Make remote CUPS printers available locally.
[  OK  ] Started Switcheroo Control Proxy service.
[  OK  ] Started Network Manager.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network is Online.
[  OK  ] Started Download data for …ailed at package install time.
[  OK  ] Started Check to see wheth…w version of Ubuntu available.
[  OK  ] Reached target Timers.
         Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
         Starting Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles...
         Starting LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon...
         Starting MySQL Community Server...
[  OK  ] Started Private Internet Access daemon.
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
         Starting TeamViewer remote control daemon...
[  OK  ] Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
[  OK  ] Started Authorization Manager.
[  OK  ] Finished Permit User Sessions.
         Starting Modem Manager...
         Starting GNOME Display Manager...
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
         Starting Hostname Service...
[  OK  ] Finished Save/Restore Sound Card State.
[  OK  ] Reached target Sound Card.
[  OK  ] Started Manage, Install and Generate Color Profiles.
[  OK  ] Started Hostname Service.
[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
```

I suspect this line could have something to do with the problem:
`[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device -1259-4770-ba01-32b86790a561.`

The device looks like the end of a UUID, so I suspected that there could be something wrong in my `fstab file`:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system>  <mount point>  <type>  <options>  <dump>  <pass>
UUID=de390d43-ceed-4756-82f9-e2af6908cb03       /tmp        ext4 noatime,errors=remount-ro  0   0
PARTUUID=c45be408-0645-4676-ad10-2faa239a802b   /boot/efi   vfat umask=0077                 0   0
UUID=ebb2d3f4-5518-4c00-9298-fb3a4b774f78       none        swap defaults                   0   0
UUID=a4a8fe1d-5017-4fed-9397-7c6463fe5d04       /           ext4 errors=remount-ro          0   0
UUID=9d66c204-fe76-4fcb-8ca3-27acc6c41576       /home       ext4 defaults                   0   2
```

But there is no UUID that matches the one that gave the error, and that ID isn't in the output from `sudo blkid` either:

```
/dev/sda6: UUID="a4a8fe1d-5017-4fed-9397-7c6463fe5d04" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="6dd08769-eae4-4a5a-a17c-776806c8c2d9"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="E6F4-51CF" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="M-dM-.M-.&" PARTUUID="cd2c4c5d-221d-425e-8125-db5e97aaf98b"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="AEC02A49C02A17DB" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="[hmg checkos]:File not exist! filena" PARTUUID="9a34299d-bc2b-4ee5-8ca3-ef51c8662cf1"
/dev/sda1: UUID="ebb2d3f4-5518-4c00-9298-fb3a4b774f78" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="b719b11d-e8b4-4232-b4a3-7ebb2884ca17"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="E6F4-51CF" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="SYSTEM" PARTUUID="c45be408-0645-4676-ad10-2faa239a802b"
/dev/sda3: UUID="9d66c204-fe76-4fcb-8ca3-27acc6c41576" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="1b7287d0-725b-49f2-ab58-3cfb09eb349f"
/dev/sda4: UUID="de390d43-ceed-4756-82f9-e2af6908cb03" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="c6e2143d-3bc0-4c80-945e-fa7945933473"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="fb34963c-9b6d-42ca-acfb-1603eb003306" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7fabbbe5-86c1-4b9d-be33-72b6fd1ac345"
/dev/sdc2: LABEL="Data" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="A2038F931B0424E6" TYPE="ntfs"
```

So now I don't know how I should proceed. I have also tried booting with all peripherals unplugged except one screen (including the NVME drive).

Answer (score 0):

You might, as I do, find the `boot-repair` utility quite useful for this.

It uses system tools `fdisk`, `parted`, `lsblk`, `blkid`, and the `/dev/disk` directory to discover all the partitions and diagnose all the labeling; as well as GRUB's `os-prober` to identify operating systems bootable therefrom.

https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/